# How to detect button action in a BLE PIN input popup

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

After connected to a BLE device, it will show a PIN number popup by system.

How to detect whether user canceled or inputed the PIN number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a very strange reason iOS does not tell you the pairing status, so you can't know anything. Depending on how the peripheral handles GATT requests, it might deny access to unpaired devices. In that case you can guess that you are paired if you got access to a characteristic you didn't previously.

If you write the peripheral's software, you can also send notifications about the pairing status.